# Using check box / radio button / progress bar in Flex 3 modules

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, module

In my project environment I have 2 projects.

MyApp & MyModule

MyApp loads MyModule. When it loads it attempts to get a class of type DisplayObject and add it to a container of itself.

The problem comes when I try to use a check box / radio button / progress bar.

The check box and radio button appear exactly like normal buttons, and the progress bar crashes:

"Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor."

Line 958 in ProgressBar.as

```
if (!_barMask)
        {
            if (FlexVersion.compatibilityVersion >= FlexVersion.VERSION_3_0)
            {
                var barMaskClass:Class = getStyle("maskSkin");
                _barMask = new barMaskClass(); // CRASH!!
            }
            else
            {
                _barMask = new UIComponent();
            }    

            _barMask.visible = true;
            _bar.addChild(DisplayObject(_barMask));
            UIComponent(_bar).mask = DisplayObject(_barMask);
        }
```

Does  anyone know how to use controls in a module correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is here:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/130211

The module needs to be loaded into the application domain.